# angular filter a scope down to 1 key type to prepare for send

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a scope that has a large chunk of key value pairs, so that I can work with it and make it do a bunch of stuff before I send it.

The problem I am having is I want to change that scope into just a small array of the keys of id with inside of it before I send it

so I have the scope which has the obect that is like this :

```
 $scope.myScope = {name: name 1, id: 1, order: 1},  {name: name 2, id: 2, order: 2}
```

And I want to turn it into

```
$scope.FilteredScope = {1,2};
```

of just the id's. I'm wondering if you can filter this scope inside of the controller before send? I've only ever used filters in stuff like repeats. so inside of the controller, it would filter out the ids and place them in maybe a new scope for sending just the ids. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use angular's filter and attach an ng-model to a text input?  Add `filter:{ name:name }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (may need to polyfill for older browsers):

```js
angular.module('MyModule', [])

.controller('MyController', function( $scope ) {
    $scope.myScope = [
      {name: 'name1', id: 1, order: 1},  
      {name: 'name2', id: 2, order: 2}
    ];
  
    $scope.ids = $scope.myScope.map( function(obj){
        return obj.id;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller='MyController'>
    ids: {{ids | json}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly** for the $scope.myScope to be a correct Javascript Object ( in this case it is an array of map Objects ), it should be of the form:

```
$scope.myScope = [{name: "name 1", id: 1, order: 1},  {name: "name 2", id: 2, order: 2}]
```

**Secondly**, if assume you want your **$scope.filteredScope** to be an array of all the **id** values from the **$scope.myScope** object.

So it can easily be done like this

```
$scope.filteredScope = []
for(entry of $scope.myScope) $scope.filteredScope.push(entry.id)
```

This will lead to an output array like **[1,2]** which you can then send it.

Please let me know if my assumptions were right.If not please edit your question with more info and I will be happy to help